# Trying to get value of checkbox from form to controller

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do something that allows me to upload photos when I check a checkbox control.  I got the client side working correctly such that when the checkbox is checked the upload controls are displayed and the form validates correctly.

However, in my controller I need to take some action if my checkbox was checked (true) calling a certain method.  If it isn't checked (false) I perform some other action.

In my html page I have the following:

```
<form action="/supplier/submit/plan" method="post" role="form" id="plan-form">
...   
   <input name="checkingPhotos" type="checkbox" id="chkPhotos" />
   <label for="chkPhotos">I want to include photos in this plan.</label>
...
</form>
```

However, in my controller I just want to for now see if I get the correct value in my checkbox.  For this I did something simple as:

```
 public function submitPlan(Request $request)
    {
        $checkboxValue = $request->input('checkingPhotos');
        dd($checkboxValue);
    }
```

The result is `null` is printed whether I check the checkbox or not.  My route also looks like this:

`Route::post('/submit/plan', 'SupplierController@submitPlan');`

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?  I just want to see the value 1 / True or 0 / False in my controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Value

The real issue is that you don't have a value for your check box.  Add a value, and your problem is solved.  It should be:

```
<input name="checkingPhotos" type="checkbox" id="chkPhotos" value="1" />
```

### `[]` creates an array

The answer Dylan Kas submitted about changeing the name to add `[]` works, but not for the reasons you think.  Lets take a look:

```
<input name="checkingPhotos[]" type="checkbox" id="chkPhotos" />
```

Will pass in the post string:

```
 checkingPhotos[]=On
```

Which, in PHP [will automatically be turned into an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#example-90).

### Refernce Frame Challenege

Why do you have a checkbox in the first place?  Is the checkbox needed? Why not just check for the existence of the file.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    //... other fields here.
    'image' => 'mime:png,gif,jpeg|max:10000' //set max to file size limit you want
]);
$plan = new SupplierPlan($validated);
if($request->has('image')){
   $plan->image = $request->image->store();
}
$plan->save();
// ... flash message, return view or redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a checkbox you should modify the name of your input to

```
<input name="checkingPhotos[]" type="checkbox" id="chkPhotos" />
```

Then you should be able to get the value as you want it with

```
$request->input('checkingPhotos');
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. When the checkbox wasn't check it returned null and when it was checked it return "On". Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is in your route, change it to

```
Route::post('/supplier/submit/plan', 'SupplierController@submitPlan');
```